# searching from the main page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, redirect, rails-routing

I am working on my first web and Rails app and can not figure out how to get a search feature work from my main page to one of the controllers.

How to send the request and redirect to a results page to show the results from the search.
I can't get this to work as am not sure how to route in a way my variable @histories will keep results and display on the show page.

I would appreciate some insight into search from any page and displaying results on a dedicated page.

Here is what i have so far in terms of the controller, model and partials.

## Shipments Model:

```
def self.search(search)
    search_condition = search
    find_by_sql("SELECT cargo_transit_histories.current_location,cargo_transit_histories.updated_at     FROM cargo_transit_histories
INNER JOIN shipments ON shipments.id = cargo_transit_histories.shipment_id WHERE  shipments.tracking_number='search_condition'")
end
```

## Tracking Controller:

```
def search
  @histories = Shipment.search(params[:search])
  render('show')
end
```

## Show (Found in Tracking view):

```
<div class="search_result">
<%= render 'track/search_results' %>
</div>
```

## _search (partial):

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'tracking', :action => 'search', :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'search_field' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %> 
  <%= link_to_function "Clear", "$('search_field').clear()" %>
<% end %>
```

## _search_results (partial):

```
<div class="Results list">

  <table class="Resultslisting" summary="Result list">
  <tr class="header">
  <th>Current Location</th>
  <th>Date/Time</th>
  </tr>
<% if !@histories.empty? %>
  <% @histories.each do |result| %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= result.current_location %></td>
  <td><%= result.updated_at %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
<% else %>
   <p> The tracking number does not exist!</p>
<% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: You should read a bit more about Rails 3 first. Routing by controller/action is deprecated. You shouldn't be writing your finder in SQL, add an association and use scopes to refine your query. The search condition at the moment won't be interpolated, and is vulnerable to SQL injection. Try [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails), it's quite good.

Comment: Hello @sj26, i have an association between the shipments and cargo_transit_histories already and will change this find. My biggest problem is how to get the results displayed on another dedicated page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following adapted example:

https://gist.github.com/4173716

But you need to dig a bit deeper into Rails 3 to understand why.

Comment: Thanks for the link it is helpful. As i mentioned on my previous comment, i am really struggling on the part of redirecting to a page that will show the contents of the @shipment for example after search is done.